# Node.js passport authentication ignores controller function

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

If passport returns the user { status: 200 }:

passport.js

```
...
return done(null, rows[0], { status: 200 });
...
```

I want the controller 'controllerLogin.login' to be called:

routs/index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const passportConf = require('../passport');
const controllerLogin = require('../controllers/login');
...

router.route('/v1/login')
    .post( function(req, res, next) {

        passport.authenticate('local-login', function (err, user, context = {}) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            if (context.status === 429) {
                return res.status(429).send({ status: 429, success: false })
            }
            if (context.status === 401){
                return res.status(401).send({ status: 401, success: false })
            }
            next();
            //return;

        })(req, res, next);

}, controllerLogin.login );
```

But I can't reach the controller 'controllerLogin.login'. What am I missing and how to execute 'controllerLogin.login'?

The below was working, but I need the upper version.

```
const passLogin = passport.authenticate('local-login', { session: false, failWithError: true });

router.route('/v1/login')
    .post( passLogin, function(err, req, res, next) {
        return res.status(401).send({ status: 401, success: false })
}, controllerLogin.login );
```

Edit: What works ...

```
router.route('/v1/login')
    .post( function(req, res, next) {

        passport.authenticate('local-login', { session: false, failWithError: false }, function (err, user, context = {}) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            if (context.statusCode === 429) {
                return res.status(429).send({ status: 429, success: false, message: { name: 'Rate Limit Error' } })
            }
            if (context.statusCode === 401){
                return res.status(401).send({ status: 401, success: false, message: { name: 'Authentication Error' } })
            }

            // this works getting user information
            console.log('user:');
            console.log(user);

            next();

        })(req, res, next);

}, /*controllerLogin.login*/ (req, res) => { res.status(200).json({just: 'testing'})} );
```

controller/login.js

```
module.exports = {
    login: async (req, res, next) => {

        // Can't access user information via 'req.user' anymore 
        console.log('req.user:');
        console.log(req.user);  

        /* .. How to access user information here?  .. */

        res.status(200).json({just: 'testing'})

  }
}
```

Comment: You might want to use a secondary function that returns a promise, and use async / await in the main function, because it looks to me like the Passport function isn't returning, and so your function never turns therefore controllerLogin.login is never called. That looks like the only difference between the 2

Comment: Thanks! Could you show me how and provide some code?

Comment: What happens when you uncomment `//next();`

Comment: @csum I get nothing returned and it runs infinitv. But it should return success and a token ...

Comment: `next()` is responsible for causing `controllerLogin.login` to be called. So it seems if you reach that `next()` line - without an error - and it then appears to hang indefinitely, maybe there's a problem with `controllerLogin.login`. Try replacing `controllerLogin.login` with `(req, res) => { res.status(200).json({just: 'testing'}) }`

Comment: @csum That's actually working. How come that controllerLogin.login won't run? Maybe because rows[0] is not passed on?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like controllerLogin.login wants `req.user`, but that is not being set. So try doing that manually in the callback you pass in to passport's `authenticate` function.

```
router.route('/v1/login')
    .post( function(req, res, next) {

        passport.authenticate('local-login', { session: false, failWithError: false }, function (err, user, context = {}) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return next(err); // might want to add this line to handle errors?
            }
            if (context.statusCode === 429) {
                return res.status(429).send({ status: 429, success: false, message: { name: 'Rate Limit Error' } })
            }
            if (context.statusCode === 401){
                return res.status(401).send({ status: 401, success: false, message: { name: 'Authentication Error' } })
            }
            if(!user) {
                // might want to handle this separately? user not found?
                //return next('User not found');
            }

            // this works getting user information
            console.log('user:');
            console.log(user);

            req.user = user;
            next(); // this moves us on to controllerLogin.login

        })(req, res, next);

}, controllerLogin.login);
```

Then in controller/login

```
module.exports = {
    login: (req, res) => {
        // remove user logging once this works, don't want to log sensitive info (!)
        console.log('req.user in controller/login:')
        console.log(req.user)

        // user logic here

        res.status(200).json({status: 200, success: true})
  }
}
```

It's worth taking a look at [passportjs docs](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/) under the "Custom Callback" section. That example doesn't pass along to another function as you are doing, but it can help to see another approach.